# Shopping Cart Rule: Buy 2 items, get 5% on 2nd; Buy 3 items, get 5% on 2nd + 10% on 3rd

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I am trying to set up a shopping cart rule like this, but I am not able to think of the best solution. This is the scenario:

> I have a product X. If user buys 2 quantities of X, he should get 5%
>   on the second X. If user buys 3 quantities of X, he should get 5% on
>   the second X and 10% on the third X.

Is there an easy way to do this via code or extension ?

I have tried setting up 2 rules for this purpose. It works almost with a little problem.

**Rule #1 (5% on 2nd X):**

```
Condition:
SKU is X
Qty in cart greater than or equal to 2
Action:
Discount Amount: 5%
Max Qty to Apply Discount: 1
Apply on Condition: SKU is X
```

This is working fine. The problem is with the 2nd rule:

**Rule #2 (10% on 3rd X):**

```
Condition:
SKU is X
Qty in cart greater than or equal to 3
Action:
Discount Amount: 10%
Max Qty to Apply Discount: 1
Apply on Condition: SKU is X
```

It says if there are 3 or more products, apply a 10% discount on one of the products. **Magento is applying the 10% discount on the already reduced 5% product** instead of the unit base price.

How do I tell Magento to apply the 10% on the most expensive product or the non-discounted product ?

One solution: Applying some mathematics, I found that if I set Rule #2 to **apply a discount of 10.5263% instead of 10%**, it works. But the decimal points differ slightly which I can live with.

My concern is I am not sure if Magento always applies this discount on the already reduced product price or the base unit price.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be achieved directly from admin configuration, need some code tweaking in Rule Validator class.

In the function 'process' of Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator class, in the case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_PERCENT_ACTION: around line #316 add the following code:

> if($rule->getId() == YOUR_RULE_ID) {    $qty = $qty - 2; }

And regarding the issue **"apply a discount of 10.5263% instead of 10%"**, you need to add 10% only in admin. As two rules are applying one after one, the second rule is considering the already applied discount to do calculation. So you need to make **Discount Qty Step (Buy X)** in admin as zero to avoid it.

Thanks,

Aravind.

Comment: Please add some information about this code tweaking, otherwise the answer is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: Updated my answer....Added information about code tweaking...

Comment: Aravind, I couldn't understand your solution. How will $qty-2 help ? Also, Discount QTY step is already 0. Could you please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I used Amasty's Special Promotions extension to accomplish this.
They have an option to specifiy discount percentage **"after N products"**

So I set 2 rules one using default Magento for the 5% discount and another one using Amasty for 10% discount on additional.

I know this is not the answer expected, well someday I will code this and post it here. Running busy now.